# Getting error while building apk in release mode in Flutter

Tags: release-mode, flutter-build

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> C:\Users\Muham.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2ebc8c16535d1d598f9826988518bd5b\transformed\material-1.5.0-beta01\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:3:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_1000 not found.

```
 C:\Users\Muham\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2ebc8c16535d1d598f9826988518bd5b\transformed\material-1.5.0-beta01\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:4:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_900 not found.

 C:\Users\Muham\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2ebc8c16535d1d598f9826988518bd5b\transformed\material-1.5.0-beta01\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:5:5-93: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_0 not found.

 C:\Users\Muham\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2ebc8c16535d1d598f9826988518bd5b\transformed\material-1.5.0-beta01\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:6:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_800 not found.

 C:\Users\Muham\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2ebc8c16535d1d598f9826988518bd5b\transformed\material-1.5.0-beta01\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:7:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_700 not found.

 C:\Users\Muham\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2ebc8c16535d1d598f9826988518bd5b\transformed\material-1.5.0-beta01\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:8:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_600 not found.

 C:\Users\Muham\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2ebc8c16535d1d598f9826988518bd5b\transformed\material-1.5.0-beta01\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:9:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_500 not found.

 C:\Users\Muham\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2ebc8c16535d1d598f9826988518bd5b\transformed\material-1.5.0-beta01\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:10:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_400 not found.

 C:\Users\Muham\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2ebc8c16535d1d598f9826988518bd5b\transformed\material-1.5.0-beta01\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:11:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_300 not found.

 C:\Users\Muham\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2ebc8c16535d1d598f9826988518bd5b\transformed\material-1.5.0-beta01\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:12:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_200 not found.

 C:\Users\Muham\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2ebc8c16535d1d598f9826988518bd5b\transformed\material-1.5.0-beta01\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:13:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_100 not found.

 C:\Users\Muham\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2ebc8c16535d1d598f9826988518bd5b\transformed\material-1.5.0-beta01\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:14:5-93: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_50 not found.

 C:\Users\Muham\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2ebc8c16535d1d598f9826988518bd5b\transformed\material-1.5.0-beta01\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:15:5-93: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_10 not found.

 C:\Users\Muham\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2ebc8c16535d1d598f9826988518bd5b\transformed\material-1.5.0-beta01\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:16:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_1000 not found.

 C:\Users\Muham\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2ebc8c16535d1d598f9826988518bd5b\transformed\material-1.5.0-beta01\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:17:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_900 not found.

 C:\Users\Muham\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2ebc8c16535d1d598f9826988518bd5b\transformed\material-1.5.0-beta01\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:18:5-101: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_0 not found.

 C:\Users\Muham\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2ebc8c16535d1d598f9826988518bd5b\transformed\material-1.5.0-beta01\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:19:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_800 not found.

 C:\Users\Muham\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2ebc8c16535d1d598f9826988518bd5b\transformed\material-1.5.0-beta01\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:20:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_700 not found.

 C:\Users\Muham\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2ebc8c16535d1d598f9826988518bd5b\transformed\material-1.5.0-beta01\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:21:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_600 not found.

 C:\Users\Muham\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2ebc8c16535d1d598f9826988518bd5b\transformed\material-1.5.0-beta01\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:22:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_500 not found.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this command in your project's directory.

```
flutter pub cache clean
```

or if you're using an older version then

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

Otherwise, you can try using a newer flutter version.
and upgrading your compileSdkVersion